A short proof that if $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}$ continuous
I learned a theorem that if $f$ is continuous and bijective then $f^{-1}$ is continuous. I went online to search for a proof and saw a really long proof in this link. However I came up with a in my opinion simpler idea and wanted to ask if it is okay.
In class we already  proved that $$f \text{ continuous at } x_0\Longleftrightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n) \quad \forall (x_n): x_n\to x_0$$
Here is my proof: $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=x_0$$
$$f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n)=f(x_0)$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)$$
(Up until this point we've only used the sequence theorem above.) Now apply $f^{-1}$:
$$f^{-1}(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n))=f^{-1}(f(x_0))$$
$$f^{-1}(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n))=x_0$$
Now we come to the crucial point. Assume $f^{-1}$ is not continuous at $x_0$. Then by the sequence theorem, there exists a sequence $(f(x_n))_n$ so that
$$f^{-1}(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(x_n))\ne \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f^{-1}(f(x_n)).$$
(Here we treated $(f(x_n))$ as the sequence in question.) However the right hand side simplifies to $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(x_n)=x_0$ and we get a contradiction: $$x_0\ne x_0.$$

Please tell us what $f$ is. Also, to quote from the [tag:solution-verification] tag description: '"Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.' Please comply with this.

$f$ is a continuous bijective function. I'm pretty sure my steps are correct until the inverse function $f^{-1}$ comes into play - I'm just not sure if I'm allowed to do that.

What is the domain and codomain of $f$? That matters for whether this result is even true. Also, your proof doesn’t make sense: to show continuity of $f^{-1}$ you need to show the sequence lemma for every convergent sequence, you only showed it for the sequences which are the image of a sequence.

@bochner.martinelli Then your proof must be false because the statement is false. There are continuous bijections whose inverse is not continuous.

Okay thank you, would you be so kind to show me where the proof exactly went wrong.

@bochner.martinelli The main problem in your argument is that you are trying to show that if $y_{n}\rightarrow y$ in the range of $f$ then $f^{-1}(y_{n})\rightarrow f^{-1}(y)$ in the domain of $f$.  Now, for each $n$, $y_{n}=f(x_{n})$ for some $x_{n}$ in the domain, and $y=f(\xi)$ for some $\xi$ in the domain. Why would you assume that $x_{n}\rightarrow \xi$ ?

@Ben Steffan This comment can be more useful if you give an example of a continuous bijection whose inverse is not continuous.

@Malady In you last comment, "... showed it for the sequences which are the image of a sequence ".  You mean to say  showed it for the sequences which are the image of a convergent sequence".

Is question restricted only to real valued functions?

The proof that you have linked assumes (a) you are considering only real-valued functions and that (b) $f$ is strictly monotone, both of which are assumptions used in the proof of the continuity of $f^{-1}$.

Consider the reals with the discrete topology; call that $B$. Consider the reals with the usual topology. Call that $U$.
Define $$
f: B \to U: x \to x.
$$
Then $f$ is continuous (because any function on a discrete space is continuous), and it's clearly bijective. On the other hand, $f^{-1}$ is a map from a connected space to a discrete space. Such a map is continuous only if it's constant.
In short: the claim you've made is false. You need a few more hypotheses.

Okay can you tell me where my claim went wrong.

I just gave you a concrete counterexample. Look at each statement you made, and ask yourself "Is this true for this concrete counterexample?" At some point, the answer will be "no", and you'll have learned something about continuity and hypotheses and about how to debug a supposed proof, both good things.

I think the problem is not applying the sequential characterization of continuity properly. For the statement, see here. In order to use the theorem we need to show that for all sequences $(x_n)$ converging to $x_0$, $f^{-1}(x_n)$ must converge to $f^{-1}(x_0)$. Equivalently, we can show that there is no sequence $(a_n)$ converging to $x_0$ such that $f^{-1}(x_0)\ne \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f^{-1}(a_n).$ The crucial point is that the sequence $(a_n)$ which caused the inequality may not be written in the form $(f(x_n))$ for any sequence $(x_n)$. (For example $f(x)$ might be equal to $0$ for some $x$ in any open interval containing $x_0$, and this prevents some of the sequences $(a_n)$ to be written in the form $(f(x_n))$ regardless however we choose the sequence $(x_n)$). So, in order to do the proof in the way you did, you need to show that if for an arbitrary sequence $(a_n)$ converging to $x_0$ we have $f^{-1}(x_0)\ne \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f^{-1}(a_n)$, then we reach a contradiction.

It seems you missed some limits inside the function's argument.

You are right @Gary. I edited the answer. Thank you for pointing it out.
